# Based on discoveries of new TNOs since 2016, is planet Nine still necessary to explain the TNO's orbits?

Tags: orbital-elements, dwarf-planets, 9th-planet, trans-neptunian-object, hypothetical

It is almost five years since the announcement of the likelyhood of another planet that is responsible for clustering eTNO's orbits, very close perihelia of detached dwarf planets to the Sun, and high inclinations of TNO's orbits. Since then there have been 316 new TNO discoveries by the Dark Energy Survey and some claim the observed clusterings are due to observational bias and that the DES disproved the necessity of planet Nine. Others still claim only a planet Nine seems to explain the observed orbits. Who is right?

Either the existence of planet Nine was really concluded from observational bias or there is indeed a likely mass that is responsible. Is Planet Nine still the most reasonable explanation for the orbital parameters of the 14 TNOs in question?

Comment: There's a recent [Astrobites article](https://astrobites.org/2020/11/11/14-kbos-point-to-planet-9/) about this.

Comment: @MikeG Thank you. Quite revealing.